# Does “I’m available” mean “I’m single”?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Does “I’m available” mean “I’m single” (not married or not had a girlfriend or a boyfriend yet) when someone asks about your relationship status?

Comment: It *could* do. Or it might just mean you're ready to start a new job, or lots of other things. Most likely for OP's context it means **I am looking for a sexual partner/significant other**.

Comment: One can be both available and in a relationship - the two obvious cases are open relationships and infidelity.

Comment: The thing is, it really **doesn't** have very much meaning out-of-context.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It can mean "I'm single" or "I'm not in a relationship."

It can also mean "I don't have any plans" - when used in conjunction with a date or time, or that you can be contacted at that point in time.

Comment: Although it sometimes ends up meaning *I'm in a relationship, but I'll still sleep with you.*

Answer (score 3):

If you're discussing relationships, "I am availible" means "I am open to dating people at this time". It most likely means single, but it could mean in an open relationship or polyamerous. "I'm availible" in that context is a way of saying "I can date you".

However, as Darwy said, it can also mean "I don't have plans", so be absolutely sure they're talking about relationships before applying that meaning if you want to avoid sitcom-esque drama.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of sentence is "context dependent". Ask yourself: "Am I available?" But wait, "available" for what? Dating? Fishing? Traveling? Working? Could be anything, but if you're discussing "relationships", yes, it does mean "I'm single", since this is the current context of the conversation.